# Spring Security ошибка при сохранении юзера

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Здравствуйте! Подскажи, пожалуйста, у меня мысли плывут ..
Использую Spring Data, Security. При регистрации юзер указывает свои имя и пароль. Я пытаюсь к этому всему добавить стандартную картинку, путь которой лежит в отдельной ячейке(по ид - 1), отдельной таблицы в бд. В таблице юзеров есть поле image_id, которое связанно внешним ключем с картинками.(Дальше кину код). Если делать без участия картинки, то регистрация проходит успешно. Собственно проблема в том, что я до конца не понимаю как должна связь произойти таблицы юзера и картинки. Как правильно? При создании юзера, отдельно создать картинку, заранее ее вписать в бд, и потом сдлать user.set(image), или достаточно просто создать картинку и сделать сет? 
И такой же точно вопрос, но если пользователь уже существует.

Пожалуйста, помогите, это крик души)

Вот часть кода, где выскакивает ешибка:

```
     Image image = imageDAO.getOne(1L);
     System.out.println(image.getPath());
```

Вот мой ImageDAO

```
public interface ImageDAO extends JpaRepository<Image, Long> {
Image findByPath(String path);
```

}

```
public interface ImageService {
void save(Image image);

Image findByPath(String path);
```

}

```
public class ImageSeviceImpl implements ImageService{
@Autowired
private  ImageDAO imageDAO;
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
public void save(Image image) {
    imageDAO.save(image);
}

@Override
public Image findByPath(String path) {
    return imageDAO.findByPath(path);
}
```

}

Возможно нужно сами классы сущностей дать.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "images")
public class Image {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "path")
private String path;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "image")
private UserEntity user;



@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
protected String username;

@Column(name = "password")
protected String password;

@Column(name = "email")
protected String email;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
protected Image image;

@Column(name = "about")
protected String about;
```

и сам код ошибки

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.chat.my.model.Image; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.chat.my.model.Image
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:210)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.save(Unknown Source)
com.chat.my.service.UserServiceImpl.save(UserServiceImpl.java:43)
com.chat.my.controller.UserController.registration(UserController.java:65)
```

Код ошибки:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Comment: Вот здесь компилятор не выдает ошибку?   
Image image = new Image("/resources/images/loaded/standart.jpg");
Image image = imageDAO.getOne(1L);
Вы два раза одну и ту же переменную объявляете

Comment: В момент авторизации привязывать картинку не есть хорошо. Авторизация нужна только для авторизации. Картинку необходимо привязывать заранее

Comment: Роман, да, там моя ошибка. Там был код под комментарием. я просто убрал, когда писал вопрос

Comment: Уберите тогда лишнюю строку, чтобы видеть актуальный код)

Comment: Роман, хорошо, я допустим уберу этот момент с автороизации. Но вопрос все равно останется.

Comment: Собственно вопрос, наверное, весь в том, какую очередность брать, при залитии картинки. 1.Сохранить в бд картинку
2. установить ее для юзера

или 
сразу установить

Comment: Эксепшн остается?

Comment: Да,он все равно останется

Comment: Может, я где-то в сущностях ошибся..

Comment: Попробуй убрать cascade = CascadeType.ALL в классе UserEntity над полем image

Comment: could not initialize proxy - no Session
...
com.chat.my.model.Image_$$_jvstaf4_2.getPath(Image_$$_jvstaf4_2.java)
 com.chat.my.service.UserServiceImpl.save(UserServiceImpl.java:40)
 com.chat.my.controller.UserController.registration(UserController.java:65)

Comment: Роман, я сейчас еще немного поправлю код в статье. Посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Ошибка no session остается. Отсюда я сделал вывод, что корень ее где-то в классах ImageDAO , ImageService, ImageServiceImpl...

Comment: Можешь код ошибки тоже выложить?

Comment: Давай не засорять комментарии, свяжись со мной по почте rdanilov.dev@gmail.com

Comment: Внизу дописал. Роман. Может мне стоит другой подход совершить просто. Я не буду картинку тут соединять. Скажите, как стоит это все сделать. Имею в виду. учитывая мою иерархию классов. Допустим в профиле юзер заливает картинку. КОторую я имею в какойто момент времени в своем котроллере. какие далее действия мои? Предполагается, что юзер уже авторизирован и существует.

Comment: написал, может в спам упало